# Kafka cluster configuration file jaas-kafka-server.conf

Tags: apache-kafka

In one our configuration file jaas-kafka-server.conf we have passwords which should be change:

```
cat jaas-kafka-server.conf
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="kafka123";
};

Client {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="kafka123";
};
```

What should be the procedure for changing such passwords to more secure? What is the impact of such operation on the Kafka cluster and applications which are connecting with Kafka?

Comment: You'll need a rolling restart to change the values... Secure in what way? Preventing access to your kafka nodes, or obfuscation of the passwords?

Comment: @OneCricketeer according to our security team the password is too simple. Your idea to obfuscation of the passwords is much better. What is the way/method to obfuscation of the passwords? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `ScramLoginModule` and class is open source on Kafka Github, similar for the Zookeeper digest, but in Zookeeper source code... The interfaces  they implement are pluggable, so you can write your own, or maybe find other implementations that exist. However, if anyone can access your server, and authenticate as a user that can read those files, you have larger issues to deal with, and hiding passwords anywhere else on disk or encoding them differently won't help much